python Tkinter executable has icon set but lost in at runtime
I need to generate an executable (onefile) from my tkinter application (one .pyw file).
PyInstaller myApp.pyw --onefile --icon=myIcon.ico

The build executable in \dist\ folder looks good - the .exe file has the icon set.
But when I run it, the program shows again the default tkInter symbol in the top left and in the windows task bar.
So whats wrong here?
Python Version: 3.7.4
PyInstaller Version: 5.13.2
See Picture.


The pyinstaller --icon option only sets the icon for the executable, not the window.
Setting the window icon will have to be done in the code. As you are using a .ico file, this can be done using iconbitmap. Should be something like this:
    import tkinter as tk
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.iconbitmap("myIcon.ico")


yes this i tried and it worked . BUT it needs then always this icon file in same folder as the .exe because it is referenced in the code. How to avoid this?
